# What is the limiting factor for algal growth in the oceans?

Tags: plant-physiology

As far as I can tell, pelagic algae require four main things to live: sunlight, carbon dioxide, trace minerals and physical space. What is the limiting factor?

Note this is kind of a deceptive question, because although it might seem straightforward, it can be tricky to figure out the limiting factor. So, in fact, there may be no definitive answer, but nevertheless I am sure there are people out there who know more about this than me, and I am hoping to get some expert insight.

Comment: Sunlight varies by the depth and lattitude so it can be the limiting factor.

Comment: Maybe other animals eating it?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Liebig's Law of the Minimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liebig%27s_law_of_the_minimum), such organisms as algae will grow until they are limited by anything that they need. So unless we start from the absurd position that all marine environments are effectively identical, the limiting factor must vary from microenvironment to microenvironment.

A trivial example would be sunlight, as suggested in the comments. The [photic zone](https://www.aos.wisc.edu/%7Ehopkins/oceans/spr_10/DSOs10supl05.html) of the ocean is only 200m deep, such that when you get deeper than that is is nearly impossible for algae to grow, due to the lack of sunlight. This is only one such limiting factor.

Another limiting nutrient that has gotten a lot of press is [iron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_fertilization). In fact, there are people who think (or have thought) that we could reverse trends in atmospheric carbon dioxide concentrations and thus global warming through iron fertilization of the oceans. (I have not been following the literature on this but I believe there is reasonable to be skeptical of the claim.)

[In other cases](http://www.gfredlee.com/Nutrients/nut_limit.pdf) it appears that the limiting nutrient is phosphorus, or nitrogen, etc. There are obvious correlates to the problems of algae blooms, eutrophication, marine [dead zones](https://serc.carleton.edu/microbelife/topics/deadzone/index.html), etc.

There is a significant amount of academic work on this that I would recommend reviewing, to see if you can figure out the answer to your underlying question:

- https://aslopubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.4319/lo.1988.33.4part2.0796
- https://www.jstor.org/stable/1352354
- https://www.srs.fs.usda.gov/pubs/chap/chap_2019_grace_001.pdf